# Access 2010 Form Population

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Its been a very long time since I have done anything with Access but I am using version 2010 I have a table that gets populated with the answers for a questionnaire, there are multiple forms to complete but the following is happening.

You login to the form, this is the first time anyone populates the form so the back table is empty, everything fills in fine.  The next person logs in, the first page of the questionnaire has all questions blank then you pick your options and then move on the second page (fine up to here), on the second page all the questions are showing answers from the first person that populated the question so somehow my 2 records have become disjointed so when competing the questionnaire as the second person I am now just overwriting the answers the first person gave.  Can anyone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong.

As suggested the navigation between forms in done using a button at the bottom of each form attached to a Macro, I don't seem to be able to show the code but in the design view the Macro Looks like this on Form 1

CloseWindows
    ObjectType
    Object Name
        Save Prompt

OpenForm
    Form Name Answers_B
    View Form
    Filter Name
    Where Condition
    Data Mode
    Window Mode Normal

If there is anything else that I can add to further assist please let me know.

Thanks Phil

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Second Page? Is that a Tab or a whole new form by itself? If it is a tab, check out how the SubForm is populated. Make sure link exists between the Main and subform.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply, its a whole new form by itself.

Comment: Have you set the Data Entry property of the form to Yes? If not the user will always default to the first record in the table.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes I have, any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you please edit your original post to show the code of how you navigate from one form to another?

Comment: Are you including the ID for the person filling out the forms in the second form's query?

Comment: I'm afraid not Ron, as I said I am very rusty on access so may not be doing this in the best way to start with, I just wanted to get something working and then could tweek when I had more time.